# How to get scanned barcode photo with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: readableObject.stringValue!);
    }
}
```

Above function works perfectly but I tried to get scanned result and write it as photo in device but it seems impossible for now.

Answer (score 0):

The way of doing that is with `CoreImage`. When you get the `readableObject.stringValue` you generate the image with the filter `CICode128BarcodeGenerator`.

So, in your example:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        let barcodeFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
        barcodeFilter?.setValue(readableObject.stringValue!.data(using: .ascii), forKey: "inputMessage")

        let image = UIImage(ciImage: (barcodeFilter?.outputImage)!)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: readableObject.stringValue!);
    }
}
```

Remember to `import CoreImage` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Is there any one way to do? Is it possible If I save scanned image from camera?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to take the barcode string from a picture? Or do you want to save the portion of the image?

Comment: I wanna save the portion of the scanned barcode image.

Comment: I wanna save the portion of the scanned barcode image and get the barcode string when I scanned.